# How to update the React state when a parameter of the state is a Map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dictionary, redux

The state of a React component in my app is of the following type:

```
interface ComponentState {
    messages: Map<string, Messages[]>;
}
```

How to update the state of the component using setState?

I tried the following, however it changes the `messages` to an `Object` from a `Map`. Also, the following is not caught by TypeScript.

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    messages: {
        ...prevState.messages,
        [someKeyAsString]: someValue,
    }
}));
```

Is there a way to use a `Map` as a state property and update it in the proper way using `setState` and also not change the type of the parameter from `Map` to `Object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's *possible* to use a Map in React, it's very odd since the code required to clone it is convoluted - you'll have to transform the Map into an entry array, then add the additional entry, then turn it back into a Map:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    messages: new Map([
      ...(prevState.messages.entries()),
     ['someKeyAsString', 'someValue']
    ])
}));
```

I'd highly recommend using a plain object instead.

Comment: Is this approach bad due to any performance reasons?

Comment: The number of keys in my Map is fairly small, however the Message[] list can be big..

Comment: Eh, since you're using React, there's no way around creating a new container for all the messages regardless. The problem is not the performance impact, so much as the uglyness of the code.

Comment: alternative syntax: `messages: new Map(prevState.messages).set('someKeyAsString', 'someValue')`